# Netezza Equivalent of CROSS APPLY

Tags: netezza, cross-apply

I am trying to migrate a query from SQL to Netezza. The original contains a custom function which I have replicated as a Stored Procedure, but now I am stuck trying to apply it to each line. The custom function was being called using a CROSS APPLY in the original code.

The stored procedure takes 3 arguments (two from the row it is being applied) and returns a single date. I need that date for each row to populate a column in the final query results.

Comment: I don't think a stored procedure will work for you here as it can't be called like a table function can within another query. If you can provide a concrete example with the original source code and data samples perhaps we can help you.

Comment: Thanks, that is pretty much what I needed to know. Abandoning the SP path now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Netezza does not support CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY (Correlated Subqueries). Maybe you can find a way to solve the problem without using these?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you'll need to change your 'coding style' a little bit to make this work, but I expect the performance to be better than you've ever expected.

If you original function were something like (pseudo code)

```
LatestPurchase(custumerID,channel)
(
Select max(order_date) 
from ordersq O
where customerID = O.CustID
And O.payment_date is not null 
And (O.salesChannel=Channel or Channel is null or Channel = 'ANY')
)
```

You should return ALL the dates for 'latest purchase' for all your customers - perhaps in a temporary table. Then you can join that result set back on your 'incoming' record.